# Modifying built-in function

Tags: python, python-3.x, overriding, built-in

Let's consider any user-defined pythonic class. If I call `dir(obect_of_class)`, I get the list of its attributes:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', ... '__weakref__', 'bases', 
'build_full_name', 'candidates', ... 'update_name'].
```

You can see 2 types of attributes in this list:

- built-in attributes,
- user defined.

I need to override `__dir__` so, that it will return only user defined attribltes. How I can do that?

It is clear, that if in overridden function I call itself, it gives me infinite recursion. So, I want to do somethig like this:

```
def __dir__(self):
        return list(filter(lambda x: not re.match('__\S*__', x), dir(self)))
```

but evade the infinite recursion.

In general, how can I modify a built-in function if I don't want to write it from scratch but want to modify the existing function?

Comment: Did you try using `dir(ClassName)` instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`super`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) to call parent's implementation of `__dir__`; avoid the recursion:

```
import re


class AClass:

    def __dir__(self):
        return [x for x in super().__dir__() if not re.match(r'__\S+__$', x)]

    def method(self):
        pass
```

---

```
>>> dir(AClass())
['method']
```

Comment: Why using generators is better than using `list(filter...))`?

Comment: @VeLKerr, It's not a generator, but a list comprehension. For me, it's a lot easier to read.

Comment: Ok, it's working, but it's very strange because `super()`-object hasn't user defined fields. So, could you explain, *why* it's working?

Comment: @VeLKerr, Please follow the link the answer. [`super`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super).

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to do it on your custom class or globally for `dir()` function?

First approach (class-only):

```
class MyClass:
    def f(self):
        return None

    def __dir__(self):
        return list(filter(lambda x: not re.match('__\S*__', x), super().__dir__()))


print(dir(MyClass()))  # ['f']
```

Basically what's done here is calling `__dir__()` of superclass (not class itself) and filtering it in subclass.

Second approach (shadowing global dir function):

```
import re


def dir(obj):
    return list(filter(lambda x: not re.match('__\S*__', x), __builtins__.dir(obj)))

print(dir({}))  # ['clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'items', 'keys', 'pop', 'popitem', 'setdefault', 'update', 'values']
```

Here all calls to `dir()` would be filtered. As you can see - it'll work for all types, including built-in types.

Comment: I want to override `__dir()__` only for my class, but thanks a lot for the explanation of the global shadowing. P.S. `super()` works for me even without arguments (I edited the post).